# Android studio 2.0 "find symbol..." doesn't search by methods

Tags: android-studio

Newest version of Android studio 'find symbol...' dialog works different as it was in 1+ versions. It searches by files, classes, properties, but not by methods. 
Is it a new 'feature' or a 'bug'? Is there any way to do a quick search by method except 'Find in path'?